# Difference between raising event with SomeEvent(arg) and SomeEvent.Invoke(arg)

Tags: c#, events

Is there any difference in using

```
SomeEvent(arg);
```

and

```
SomeEvent.Invoke(arg);
```

If there is no significant difference, which one is the better practice?

Comment: Thanks everyone. All answers are quite similar, so I picked the first one answered the question completely...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first form is C# syntactic sugar for the second.  I've not seen anyone use the second form, but I can imagine that some code-generators might in order to "future-proof" the code.

Answer (score 1):

No difference, they are equivalent.   `SomeEvent(arg);` is just syntactic sugar for `.Invoke`

Answer (score 1):

They are exactly the same.  The convention is to use the first form though.